# run Gunicorn with WSGI inside a folder

Tags: python, django, gunicorn

I have my project structure as below. I use folders to put all the settings files in them.

```
~/myproject/
           - env
           - server
                 - api
                 - home
                     - settings
                         - dev.py
                         - prod.py
                     - wsgi
                         - dev.py
                         - prod.py
```

the myproject/server/home/wsgi/dev.py is:

```
import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "home.settings.dev")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

also inside myproject/server/home/settings/dev.py is:

```
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'home.wsgi.dev.application'
```

with all the above setup the server runs perfectly. When i try to deploy and run the gunicorn, it just fails. Here is my gunicorn.service:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=demouser
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/demouser/myproject
ExecStart=/home/demouser/myproject/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/demouser/myproject.sock home.wsgi.dev:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I am not sure why i get this error as the gunicorn never starts:

```
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/gunicorn.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-08-30 05:04:48 UTC; 14min ago
  Process: 13354 ExecStart=/home/demouser/myproject/env/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/
 Main PID: 13354 (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Aug 30 05:04:48 localhost systemd[1]: Started gunicorn daemon.
Aug 30 05:04:48 localhost systemd[13354]: gunicorn.service: Failed to execute command: No such file or directory
Aug 30 05:04:48 localhost systemd[13354]: gunicorn.service: Failed at step EXEC spawning /home/demouser/myproject/env/
Aug 30 05:04:48 localhost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Aug 30 05:04:48 localhost systemd[1]: gunicorn.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
~
```

i hope i made things clear for everyone. thanks

Answer (score 0):

I solved it and here is how if you are interested:

I have installed Gunicorn3 and then i changed the gunicorn.service file and edited these lines :

```
WorkingDirectory=/home/demouser/myproject/server
ExecStart=/usr/bin/gunicorn3 --access-logfile - --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/demouser/myproject.sock home.wsgi.dev:application
```